# How do I retain the key name in the result using a lodash .map()?

Tags: javascript, lodash

```
log(_.map(businessOpenSlots, weekday => {
        return _.spread(_.union)(_.map(weekday, slot => {
           return this.getTimeStops(slot.open, slot.close);
        }))
    } ))
```

This is code above is printing below. However, instead of 0..4, I want to key to be weekday.

Not sure how to best achieve this.

[image]

the `businessOpenSlots` data is below

```
{
   "friday":[
      {
         "open":"0900",
         "close":"1700"
      }
   ]"monday":[
      {
         "open":"0800",
         "close":"1530"
      },
      {
         "open":"1730",
         "close":"1930"
      }
   ]"thursday":[
      {
         "open":"0900",
         "close":"1700"
      }
   ]"tuesday":[
      {
         "open":"24hrs",
         "close":"24hrs"
      }
   ]"wednesday":[
      {
         "open":"0900",
         "close":"1700"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: I think those values are not keys, but indexes. Map returns an array, so you have an array of arrays as result.

Comment: I wish my index numbers to be weekday key names though. I will still want an array of arrays, but the indices to be as I specify.

Comment: Here is the console log result. If you want to relate times with days you can define both in an object. After that, you can access the day of a certain time.

Comment: I guess you both are right. I am wrong. I actually want an object of arrays with keys as the weekdays, and here I am outputting an array of arrays. Right, back to work, thank you. Will post an update soon

Comment: Please include sample input data and requested output in your question.

Comment: You might be able to call [`zipObject`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#zipObject) on the array of weekday names and the result above.

Comment: @ScottSauyet `businessOpenSlots` isn't an array. It's an object, with key names as weekdays and inside them are arrays.

Comment: again, please supply data, not images of it.  But that console image certainly *looks* like an array.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Sure, check the last part of the question. Sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution myself and posting it here for the community.

I just had to use `_.mapValues()` from Lodash.

```
let availableSlots = _.mapValues(businessOpenSlots, function(slots, weekday) {
       return _.spread(_.union)(_.map(slots, slot => {
          return vm.getTimeStops(slot.open, slot.close);
       }))
    });
log(availableSlots)
```

It returns the following, just as I wanted.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this relatively simply with vanilla JS.  Here's one version:

```js
const hoursToTimeStops = businessOpenSlots =>
  Object .fromEntries (
    Object .entries (businessOpenSlots) .map (([d, h]) => [d, h .flatMap (vm .getTimeStops)])
  )

const businessOpenSlots = {monday: [{open: "0800", close: "1530"}, {open: "1730", close: "1930"}], tuesday: [{open: "24hrs", close: "24hrs"}], wednesday: [{open: "0900", close: "1700"}], thursday: [{open: "0900", close: "1700"}], friday: [{open: "0900", close: "1700"}]}

console .log (hoursToTimeStops (businessOpenSlots))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script> // Dummy implementation for `vm`.
const every15mins = (sh, sm, eh, em) => sh * 60 + sm > eh * 60 + em ? [] : [`${String(sh).padStart(2, '0')}:${String(sm).padStart(2, '0')}`, ...every15mins(sh + (sm >= 45 ? 1 : 0), (sm + 15) % 60, eh, em)]
const vm = {getTimeStops:  ({open, close}) => open === '24hrs' ? ["00:00"] : every15mins(Number(open.slice(0, 2)), Number(open.slice(2, 4)), Number(close.slice(0, 2)), Number(close.slice(2, 4)))}
</script>
```

The process of calling `entries`, `map`ping the results, then calling `fromEntries` is nicely encapsulated by lodash's `mapValues` (or Ramda's `map`.)  But the remainder of this seems simpler than your lodash version.

However, I believe you should be able to simplify that version quite a bit.  I'm much more familiar with Ramda (disclaimer: I'm one of its authors), and I know that in Ramda, we could [simply write](https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.27.0#?%2F%2F%20dummy%20version%20of%20vm%0Aconst%20every15mins%20%3D%20%28sh%2C%20sm%2C%20eh%2C%20em%29%20%3D%3E%20sh%20%2A%2060%20%2B%20sm%20%3E%20eh%20%2A%2060%20%2B%20em%20%3F%20%5B%5D%20%3A%20%5B%60%24%7BString%28sh%29.padStart%282%2C%20%270%27%29%7D%3A%24%7BString%28sm%29.padStart%282%2C%20%270%27%29%7D%60%2C%20...every15mins%28sh%20%2B%20%28sm%20%3E%3D%2045%20%3F%201%20%3A%200%29%2C%20%28sm%20%2B%2015%29%20%25%2060%2C%20eh%2C%20em%29%5D%0Aconst%20vm%20%3D%20%7BgetTimeStops%3A%20%20%28%7Bopen%2C%20close%7D%29%20%3D%3E%20open%20%3D%3D%3D%20%2724hrs%27%20%3F%20%5B%2200%3A00%22%5D%20%3A%20every15mins%28Number%28open.slice%280%2C%202%29%29%2C%20Number%28open.slice%282%2C%204%29%29%2C%20Number%28close.slice%280%2C%202%29%29%2C%20Number%28close.slice%282%2C%204%29%29%29%7D%0A%0A%2F%2F%20main%20function%0Aconst%20hoursToTimeStops%20%3D%20map%20%28chain%20%28vm.getTimeStops%29%29%0A%0A%2F%2F%20data%0Aconst%20businessOpenSlots%20%3D%20%7Bmonday%3A%20%5B%7Bopen%3A%20%220800%22%2C%20close%3A%20%221530%22%7D%2C%20%7Bopen%3A%20%221730%22%2C%20close%3A%20%221930%22%7D%5D%2C%20tuesday%3A%20%5B%7Bopen%3A%20%2224hrs%22%2C%20close%3A%20%2224hrs%22%7D%5D%2C%20wednesday%3A%20%5B%7Bopen%3A%20%220900%22%2C%20close%3A%20%221700%22%7D%5D%2C%20thursday%3A%20%5B%7Bopen%3A%20%220900%22%2C%20close%3A%20%221700%22%7D%5D%2C%20friday%3A%20%5B%7Bopen%3A%20%220900%22%2C%20close%3A%20%221700%22%7D%5D%7D%0A%0A%2F%2F%20demo%0AhoursToTimeStops%20%28businessOpenSlots%29):

```js
const hoursToTimeStops = map (chain (vm.getTimeStops))
```

and I'm guessing you could get something similar using lodash's `mapValues` in place of `map` and its `flatMap` in place of `chain`.  (It probably wouldn't be quite as elegant unless you used Lodash FP, but it wouldn't be that far off.)

Comment: Very nice, I am looking into Ramda.